# WSO2 APIM 2.0 Clustering manage/monitor in carbon UI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I deployed the cluster in one server, here is the node start log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:41,596]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Cluster domain: wso2.pubstore.domain {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:41,596]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Loading hazelcast configuration from axis2 clustering configuration {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:41,620]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Using wka based membership management scheme {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:41,628]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils} -  Added member: Host:10.222.47.201, Remote Host:null, Port: 4006, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:41,628]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils} -  Added member: Host:10.222.47.201, Remote Host:null, Port: 4007, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.util.MemberUtils}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:47,768]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  Starting polling event receivers {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,176]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Hazelcast initialized in 8544ms {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,274]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Local member: [faedd3de-2842-4447-a84e-0db43c86595d] - Host:10.222.47.201, Remote Host:null, Port: 4006, HTTP:8285, HTTPS:8248, Domain: wso2.pubstore.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,664]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.cluster.coordination.hazelcast.HazelcastAgent} -  Initializing Hazelcast Agent {org.wso2.andes.server.cluster.coordination.hazelcast.HazelcastAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,676]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.cluster.coordination.hazelcast.HazelcastAgent} -  Successfully initialized Hazelcast Agent {org.wso2.andes.server.cluster.coordination.hazelcast.HazelcastAgent}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,686]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  CEP started with clustering enabled, but SingleNode configuration given. {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,697]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent} -  Cluster initialization completed {org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent}
```

From carbon UI, 
[image]

It seems carbon UI can't display cluster information. 
So, my question is that can carbon UI display cluster information?

Comment: What kind of information you want to display?

Comment: I installed 2 nodes, but i can't find such information in carbon .

Comment: Is it related to "TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-02 03:55:50,686]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  CEP started with clustering enabled, but SingleNode configuration given. {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService}"? what's the possible configure issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, As far as I know you can't view cluster related information from UI. However, you can see whether the nodes are correctly joined or not by logs. Check for `member joined` log messages in all consoles.

**Example:**

```
INFO - WKABasedMembershipScheme Member joined [057c1105-97b2-4c99-8b1d-4164127b5684]: /192.168.1.100:4200
```

Note: To provide a complete answer kindly provide the post or article your following.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i can find such log messages.